# How do I highlight specific bar/s using vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite

New to vega-lite. How do I highlight specific bar/s using vega-lite.

For example, how do I highlight the bars for Documentary and Drama in red (eg ...#dd2525) leaving the remaining bars (grey #4682b4). Thanks.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 200,
  "height": {"step": 16},
  "data": {"url": "data/movies.json"},
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "Major Genre",
      "type": "nominal",
      "axis": null
    }
  },
  "layer": [{
    "mark": {"type": "bar", "color": "#ddd"},
    "encoding": {
      "x": {
        "aggregate": "mean",
        "field": "IMDB Rating",
        "scale": {"domain": [0, 10]},
        "title": "Mean IMDB Ratings"
      }
    }
  }, {
    "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "left", "x": 5},
    "encoding": {
      "text": {"field": "Major Genre"},
      "detail": {"aggregate": "count"}
    }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add params as `select` and use the param name as `condition` in encoding. Check [documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/selection.html) for more.

Below is the code snippet or refer [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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).

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 200,
  "height": {"step": 19},
  "data": {"url": "data/movies.json"},
  "encoding": {"y": {"field": "Major Genre", "type": "nominal", "axis": null}},
  "layer": [
    {
      "params": [
        {"select": {"encodings": ["y"], "type": "point"}, "name": "barSelect"}
      ],
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "color": "#ddd"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "aggregate": "mean",
          "field": "IMDB Rating",
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 10]},
          "title": "Mean IMDB Ratings"
        },
        "color": {
          "condition": {"param": "barSelect", "value": "red", "empty": false},
          "value": "#ddd"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "left", "x": 5},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "Major Genre"},
        "detail": {"aggregate": "count"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Edit**

For a static view without changing the color on click, you can simply provide the field and value in condition for which you want to apply colors. Refer the below snippet or [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgBMABh1L4NMljSgImODjQBGAJwBfJWqSYUqUAwBOgtCGeuCBDZiGjgIKRl5RxA4WSg2NRpZMlMQAE9UgDNQwTVfAFkkSTZPAAIAcVjPOEUQTDScGvRZNgQkpB8lJAAPGgg0WQZBQXtowSQ0uE80AG1QZE8Aa1T6xt8mJGmleMES3wBiNSOQaNj4xOTU7tSkMjJqigtfBDgkeSVsuFzfAEl8gBEAEKlABKLiSKSU0A6TVAalaSCSs301h0AF1opg6IImiB8q9ZKU-kDQeDkv1ojs9u4QPFZIksXJZqBiB0GLjqnklBZzFkcnl0IVimVKrJqrU5HAAPKZWYgf6eJDIWr-NhQBgvWSuTwZDH2NFKVmCdkHI55UaOeabZY01a4izdTC1DpGeToHGZJ1Ka6oMSnOIJCErOCOvlfAV4oolCpVGrRNRwVw0Hw0273PhPdDxBhak6jDFAA)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 200,
  "height": {"step": 19},
  "data": {"url": "data/movies.json"},
  "encoding": {"y": {"field": "Major Genre", "type": "nominal", "axis": null}},
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "color": "#ddd"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "aggregate": "mean",
          "field": "IMDB Rating",
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 10]},
          "title": "Mean IMDB Ratings"
        },
        "color": {
          "condition": [
            {
              "value": "red",
              "test": {"field": "Major Genre", "oneOf": ["Drama", "Documentary"]}
            }
          ],
          "value": "#ddd"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "left", "x": 5},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "Major Genre"},
        "detail": {"aggregate": "count"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and code. But was actually hoping to have a static visual with the two mentioned bars coloured red (ie., rather than appear red after a mouse click). Maybe highlight was wrong word to use.

Comment: Example can be found below ......                                                                                              https://huppenkothen.org/data-visualization-tutorial/fig/output_36_2.png

Comment: Thanks for the updated code and explanation. Much appreciated.